# Windows 10 Updates are not anymore working

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1903

I have a problem with my Windows 10 Education x64 Edition, Version 1803, Build 17134.590.

Since the Windows 10 Juni 2019 cumulative update was released, my Windows Update is not working on my system. Every time, the computer is restarted, the update fails with the error code 0x80073712.

Please **help me**, how to deal with this, **without reinstalling my system** (that is actually not possible).

Steps I already tried, but no positive result:

1. I ran the Windows Update Troubleshooter.
2. I downloaded this update manually and tried to install manual. No success.
3. Tried to manually reset the Windows Update system (followed instructions from [here](https://pureinfotech.com/reset-windows-update-windows-10-fix-downloads-installs/))
4. Tried to run DISM ans SFC to repair corrupted system files, using following commands:

   > ```
   > DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
   > sfc /scannow
   > ```
5. Try to remove pending.xml file under WinSXS folder.
6. Tried to updgrade from 1803 to 1903. Upgrade failed and rolled back to 1803.

Windows Update results logs are available (not possible to attach here, but I can send it).

DISM and Windows Update logs are available (but could not attach here because of limits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have tried everything then visit this link: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Then click on update now...you will get updated to windows 10 v 1903 and windows update will be fixed.

You can try the below link also:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors

Comment: The first link (update to 1903) was not tried. I will do it.
But the FIX link, I already done it.

Comment: Also tried to 1903. It failed and rolled back to 1803.

Answer (score 0):

One more troubleshooting for Windows Update that is not found in your link:

**Remove Pending Xml File**

In an elevated Command Prompt run:

```
net stop trustedinstaller
cd %windir%\winsxs
takeown /f pending.xml /a
cacls pending.xml /e /g everyone:f
del pending.xml
```

---

As none of the remedies you tried have worked, I suggest to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), using the
[latest installation media](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9230-download-windows-10-iso-file.html).

This will upgrade Windows to version 1903 and probably fix the problem,
while still preserving user accounts, user data and apps,
and most Windows settings.

I would suggest first to take good backups of your data, and if possible
take a backup image of the system disk in a restorable format and on another
disk.

Comment: It is tried, but without success. Sorry

Comment: I added a second part.

Answer (score 0):

OK then do this :
Download Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft website 
Run the bootable USB and click on "Repair your computer"
worth a try !!

Comment: If you try in-place upgrade , it will remove your apps.
-"In Windows 10, this feature no longer preserves user-acquired Windows apps."

Comment: Where did you get this information from? And why did you add second answer?

Comment: i am new and it was not allowing me to comment...i got the information from the link you posted !!

Comment: Can't you read? This was for Refresh, not for In-place Upgrade. And you can always edit your own answer - reading our site  help would also be useful.

Comment: i could't have edited my own answer..because that was a different a different Elmo account and this one is different.
as I told you before also ...I am new here so i am getting to understand things , you don't need to behave in this rude way, be nice to people.
As for the apps, my mistake I was reading too fast.

Comment: OK, on the Net good behavior is called Netiquette. One of the good behavior rules on this site is not to "adopt" answers of other people, which is what you have done, and what has caused my strongly-worded comment. I apologize if you did this in all innocence, but you should really think carefully about Netiquette and mutual respect. To conclude: Welcome to our site, and good luck.

Comment: I did not "adopt" your answer.I just read it after I posted mine. Thank you.