# Windows Store error "Turn on Windows Update"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-store

I cannot download any app from the Microsoft Store on Windows 10. I get the following error message:

**Turn on Windows Update**

```
Windows Update is disabled. You can repair Windows Update by running the Windows Update troubleshooter in Settings.
```

I have checked windows updates, it says

```
You're up to date
Last checked: Today
```

I have run the updates troubleshooter, but there is not any error.

Also I can see in the services that Windows Update service is "**Running**" (startup type: Manual).
How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 are you on? Try also *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter*.

Comment: One possibility: Windows Update broke it's own Store. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-v1909-update-causes-windows-store/59d45a83-896b-444d-bbea-cc845d8f6640

Comment: @harrymc Windows 10 Pro N, Version 1909. OS Build 18363.900. Troubleshooter doesnt find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows Update troubleshooter didn't help, there are still other manipulations
that can be done that you may see in the post
[Windows 10 Updates are not anymore working](https://superuser.com/questions/1457218/windows-10-updates-are-not-anymore-working).

However, there is no guarantee that any of them will improve the situation.
You might as well break out the big gun now, to return all Windows components
to a known good state.

Download the latest Windows 10 ISO and install it as described in the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If this does not work, boot into Safe mode and repeat the above.